# How to repaint walls in bedroom after painting with latex over oil based flat paint

Tags: oil-based-paint

Painted with latex eggshell paint over old sponged oil based finish on walls of bedroom.  Finger can scrape off paint by headboard.

Do I need to strip all latex paint before repainting or can I prime over the latex currently on the walls and start over?

Please advise.

Comment: a chain's only as strong as the weakest link, but if you put a thick primer on, it might be enough side-structure to keep fingernails from uplifting the weak layer and flaking.

Comment: You need to properly prepare the surface by cleaning and sanding it before applying fresh paint. They also make paint / primer to be used in cases like this. It will be work but if you are careful it will look great when you are finished.